How to use TextIndexed with subDocument (MongoDB & Java)
I have a document with name User and this document has subDocument with name UserIdentifier like below:
@Data
@Document
public class User {

    private List<UserIdentifier> userIdentifierList;

    @TextIndexed(weight = 3)
    private String firstName;

    @TextIndexed(weight = 2)
    private String lastName;
....
}


@Data
public class UserIdentifier {

    private String identifierValue;
.....

}

I want to create text index for firstName with weight : 3 lastName with weight: 2 and userIdentifierList.userIdentifierValue with weight : 1 (let's say default weight).
So how can I create text index for these fields and with weights?
I tried to use @CompoundIndex annotation but it is not support weight definition and then tried to use @CompoundIndex for just userIdentifierList.userIdentifierValue field and tried to create index for firstName and lastName with @TextIndexed(weight = x) but I can't build my code because of index conflict.
